# CSS Grid change on small screens

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm building a responsive Navbar by CSS grid.
i divided Navbar grid into 4 columns and 1 row.
and everything goes well on desktop screens.

(on screens max-width:952px): overlap between grid elements occur.
(on screens max-width:858px): grid gives me 2 rows though i define it as 1 row.

what do i miss in my code?

here is html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Markvira</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <!-- icon library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Local CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles/styles.css' %}">
  </head>

  <body>

    <!--Wrapper to wrap everything-->
    <div class="grid-container">

      <div class="Header">

        <input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
        <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </label>

        <div class="brand-img">
          <a href=""><img src="{% static 'images/markvira-logo.png' %}" alt=""> </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="main-links">
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="sm-links">
          <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-whatsapp"></a></li>
        </ul>
        
    </div>

      <main class="main-index">

        <div class="index-SecA">
          <h1>Hero</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="SecB">
          <h1>Hero</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="SecC">
          <h1>Mark-vira</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="SecD">
          <h1>What-offer</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="SecE">
          <h1>Why-Us</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="SecF">
          <h1>Last-Client</h1>
        </div>
      </main>

      <div class="Footer">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--End of Wrapper-->
  </body>
</html>
```

here is css

```
/*Header*/
.Header{
    grid-area: hd;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows:auto;
    align-items: center;
    background:#dcdcdc8c;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: fixed; /* to make header sticky at top on scroll*/
    width: 100%;
}

.brand-img{
    grid-column: 1/2;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content:start;
}

.brand-img img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 75px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.main-links{
    grid-column: 2/4;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

.main-links li{
    list-style: none;
}

.main-links a{
    margin: 0px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: poppins;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #ffff;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

.main-links a:hover{
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid brown;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.main-links a.hover{
    color: blue;
    border-bottom: 3px solid brown;

}

.sm-links{
    grid-column: 4/5;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

.sm-links li{
    list-style: none;
}

.sm-links a{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0px 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center; /*make social media icons at the center of black circle background*/
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffff;
    background: black;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.sm-links .fa-facebook:hover{
    color: #3b5998;
    border: 2px solid #3b5998;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #3b5998;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sm-links .fa-instagram:hover{
    color: #c32aa3;
    border: 2px solid #c32aa3;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #c32aa3;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sm-links .fa-twitter:hover{
    color: #1da1f2;
    border: 2px solid #1da1f2;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #1da1f2;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sm-links .fa-youtube:hover{
    color: #ff0000;
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ff0000;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sm-links .fa-linkedin:hover{
    color: #007bb6;
    border: 2px solid #007bb6;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #007bb6;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sm-links .fa-whatsapp:hover{
    color: #25d366;
    border: 2px solid #25d366;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #25d366;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.checkbtn{
    grid-column: 4/5;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: black;
    justify-self: center;
    line-height: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;

}

#check{
    display: none;
}


@media (max-width:952px){
    .brand-img img{
        width: 90px;
        height: 65px;
        margin-left: 15px;
    }

    .main-links a{
        margin: 0px 8px;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    .sm-links a{
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin: 0px 3px;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    
}


@media (max-width:858px){

    .checkbtn{
        display: block;
    }

    .main-links, .sm-links{
        display: none; 
        text-align: center;       
        width: 50%;
    }

    li{
        display: block;
    }

    #check:checked ~ ul {
        left: 0;
        display: block;

    }
}
```

[image: a screenshot for Navbar at small screen]

Comment: Does the content fit inside one row?

Comment: yes, at desktop only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your brand image goes on next row when burger appears.

You need to set that is in first row.

```
.brand-img {
    grid-column: 1/2;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: start;
    grid-row: 1;
}
```

Comment: but why grid changes into two rows in small screens though i define it with one row?

Comment: Because you put menu burger on social icons place .. no matter it's display:none; that's how you explicitly defined them